# Solving trigonometric equation with power

Tags: trigonometry

If $$\sin^2x=\frac{1}{2}$$
then $$\sin x=\frac{1}{\pm\sqrt{2}}$$
Solving for $\sin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, I get $$x=2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}, \quad 2k\pi+\frac{3}{4}\pi$$ and for the negative square root 
$$x=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}, \quad 2k\pi-\frac{3}{4}\pi$$ 
so by combining the two
$$x=2k\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{4}, \quad 2k\pi\pm\frac{3}{4}\pi$$

However WolframAlpha gives $x=k\pi\pm\pi/4$

My question is how do I simplify my answer to get this or what method do I use to get this answer? I've looked through my notes but nothing involves the "$^2$" in the question.

Comment: Minor typo, you mean $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer WolframAlpha is giving is simply a combination of the answers you got. You can see it by looking at where the points you found fall on a unit circle.

For example, Wolfram tells you that for k=1, $x=\pi + \pi /4$ is a solution. This is equivalent to taking your solution for k = 1, and $x = 2\pi - 3\pi/4$

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

$x=2k\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{4}$ will get answers in the first and fourth quadrants.

$x=2k\pi \pm \frac{3\pi}{4}$ will get answers in the second and third quadrants.

Whereas $x=k\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{4}$ will get answers in all quadrants.

Let $k=1$ or $2$ and draw the resulting angles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$, so $\sin^2x=(1-\cos2x)/2$ and your equation becomes
$$
\cos2x=0
$$
producing
$$
2x=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
$$
and so
$$
x=\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi
$$

However, your solution is as good as this one.